# Getting a single instance when calling a script multiple times

Tags: python, selenium, singleton

How would you create an instance of a `webdriver` the first time the script is called, and then retrieve that same instance the next times? Something like this pseudocode:

```
from selenium import webdriver

thisScript = FIXME

if thisScript.isRunning():
    driver = thisScript.driver

else:        
    driver = webdriver.Firefox()

driver.get("http://www.example.com")
```

Comment: "next time the script is called" Do you mean your script runs to completion and you want to use the same driver? Or do you mean that if you import your module multiple places in a larger program, it will always provide back the same driver instance?

Comment: @unholysampler The first option, it should run to completion

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best option seems to be setting up a server/client system, I guess it could be done using the selenium server, but I wound up coding my own, something like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
#-*- coding:utf-8 -*-
# This script takes a html file name as argument to start the
# selenium webdriver. It will start a server the first time it's run.
# If called again, it will then check if the server is running
# and restart it if neccessary. This prevents from having to restart
# the browser when running tests from different scripts by facilitating
# the running instance of selenium.

import socket, threading, time, commands, os

from selenium import webdriver

dirPath = "/path/to/dir"
fileUri = "/path/to/file"

class ThreadServer(threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self, port=None, host=None):
        threading.Thread.__init__(self)

        self.host = host if host != None else "localhost"
        self.port = port if port != None else self.getFreePort()

        self.driver = webdriver.Firefox()

    def getFreePort(self):
        sock = socket.socket()
        sock.bind(('', 0))

        port = sock.getsockname()[1]

        sock.close()

        return port

    def run(self):
        server = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
        server.bind((self.host, self.port))

        port = server.getsockname()[1]
        print 'Server started successfully {0}'.format(port)

        server.listen(1)
        conn, addr = server.accept()

        while 1:
            try:
                fileUrl = conn.recv(4096)

            except socket.error:
                server.listen(1)
                conn, addr = server.accept()
                continue

            if not fileUrl:
                server.listen(1)
                conn, addr = server.accept()

            else:
                self.driver.get(fileUrl)

host = '127.0.0.1'
port = 44164

if dirPath == "/path/to/dir":
    fileUrl = 'http://localhost/{0}'.format(fileUri.lstrip(dirPath))

    try:
        sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET,socket.SOCK_STREAM)
        sock.settimeout(3.0)
        sock.connect((host, port))

    except socket.error:
        threadServer = ThreadServer(port)
        threadServer.start()

        time.sleep(3)

        sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET,socket.SOCK_STREAM)
        sock.settimeout(3.0)
        sock.connect((host, port))

    try:
        sock.send(fileUrl)

    except socket.error:
        raise

    else:
        sock.close()
```